# Is it possible to disable the Action Bar purely with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

In an app that I am working on, I wanted to delete the `themes.xml` file, since I plan to only use Jetpack Compose's MaterialTheme. I deleted it along with the references to it in `AndroidManifest.xml`. This seems to have worked fine, except for one thing. There is now an Action Bar visible at the top of my app, like in this example:
[Image of an Action Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1tWu.png)

It seems that the Action Bar was not there in the first place because of this line in the `themes.xml` file:

```
<style name="Theme.Inventory" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
```

My question is: is it possible to disable the Action Bar without the use of XML?

I tried searching for how I can manipulate this default Action Bar with Jetpack Compose, but was not able to find an answer. I know that you can modify elements such as the Status Bar and the Navigation Bar with a SystemUiController, but I am not aware if that is what I am supposed to use.